# Creating a Unicode XML from scratch with Python 3.2

Tags: python, xml, unicode, python-3.x, xml.etree

So basically, I want to generate an XML with elements generated from data in a python dictionary, where what will come to be tags are the dictionary's keys, and the text the dictionary's values.  I have no need to give attributes to the items, and my desired output would look something like this:

```
<AllItems>

  <Item>
    <some_tag> Hello World </some_tag>
    ...
    <another_tag />
  </Item>

  <Item> ... </Item>
  ...

</AllItems>
```

I have tried using the xml.etree.ElementTree package, by creating a tree, setting an Element "AllItems" as the root like so:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

def dict_to_elem(dictionary):
    item = et.Element('Item')
    for key in dictionary:
        field = et.Element(key.replace(' ',''))
        field.text = dictionary[key]
        item.append(field)
    return item

newtree = et.ElementTree()
root = et.Element('AllItems')
newtree._setroot(root)

root.append(dict_to_elem(  {'some_tag':'Hello World', ...}  )
# Lather, rinse, repeat this append step as needed

with open(  filename  , 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    tree.write(file, encoding='unicode')
```

In the last two lines, I have tried omitting the encoding in the open() statement, omitting and changing to 'UTF-8' the encoding in the write() method, and I either get an error that "') is type str is not serializable

**So my problem** - All I want to know is how should I be going about creating a UTF-8 XML from scratch with the format above, and is there a more robust solution using another package, that will properly allow me to handle UTF-8 characters?  I'm not married to ElementTree for a solution, but I would prefer not to have to create a schema. Thanks in advance for any advice/solutions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, the `ElementTree` is a good choice. If you need a bit more capable package in future, you can switch to the third party `lxml` module that uses the same interface.

The answer to your problem can be found in the doc http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write

> The output is either a string (str) or binary (bytes). This is controlled by the encoding argument. If encoding is "unicode", the output is a string; otherwise, it’s binary. Note that this may conflict with the type of file if it’s an open file object; make sure you do not try to write a string to a binary stream and vice versa.

Basically, you are doing it correctly. You `open()` the file in a text mode, this way the file accepts the strings and you neet to use the `'unicode'` argument for the `tree.write()`. Otherwise, you could open the file in binary mode (no encoding argument in the `open()`) and use the `'utf-8'` in the `tree.write()`.

A bit cleaned-up code that works on its own:

```
#!python3
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

def dict_to_elem(dictionary):
    item = et.Element('Item')
    for key in dictionary:
        field = et.Element(key.replace(' ',''))
        field.text = dictionary[key]
        item.append(field)
    return item

root = et.Element('AllItems')     # create the element first...
tree = et.ElementTree(root)       # and pass it to the created tree

root.append(dict_to_elem(  {'some_tag':'Hello World', 'xxx': 'yyy'}  ))
# Lather, rinse, repeat this append step as needed

filename = 'a.xml'
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    tree.write(file, encoding='unicode')

# The alternative is...    
fname = 'b.xml'
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    tree.write(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

It depends on the purpose. Of the two, I personally prefer the first solution. It clearly says that you write a text file (and the XML is a text file).

But the simplest alternative where you do not need to tell the encoding is just to pass the file name to the `tree.write` like this:

```
tree.write('c.xml', encoding='utf-8')
```

It opens the file, writes the content *using the given encoding* (updated after the Sebastian's comment below), and closes the file. And you can read it easily and you can do no mistake here.

Comment: note: `tree.write()` uses ascii without explicit `encoding` parameter.  It converts all non-ascii characters to xml character references e.g., `'☺' -> '&#9786'`.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the info, Sebastian. I did not checked that. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't be necessary but you could add xml declaration explicitly if your tool doesn't understand the generated xml file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

your_dict = {'some_tag': 'Hello World ☺'}

def add_items(root, items):
    for name, text in items:
        elem = etree.SubElement(root, name)
        elem.text = text

root = etree.Element('AllItems')
add_items(etree.SubElement(root, 'Item'),
          ((key.replace(' ', ''), value) for key, value in your_dict.items()))
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('output.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

#### output.xml:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<AllItems><Item><some_tag>Hello World ☺</some_tag></Item></AllItems>
```

Comment: trying to run the exact same snippet, but getting an error
TypeError: escape_cdata_carriage_return() missing 1 required positional argument: 'encoding'

Comment: @RohithYeravothula the code in the answer [works](https://ideone.com/D9jNYi) as is on Python 3.5.1 too.

Comment: yeah my bad, another script was overwriting a core function of ElementTree and that caused the issue. Above snippet works absolutely fine on python 3.6 too